# PAD offset from HERE

Tags: forth

The version of Forth I am using (Mecrisp) lacks the PAD word.  However, it has HERE.  Now, I guess I could define PAD myself using something like:

```
hex deadbeef constant offset
: pad here offset + ;
```

My question is how can I find a safe value of the offset?  Indeed, is it safe for the offset to be zero bytes - which I guess makes PAD equivalent to HERE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A safe way is to allocate a dedicated buffer for PAD in the dictionary (via [`ALLOT`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/ALLOT)) or dynamically in memory (via [`ALLOCATE`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/memory/ALLOCATE)).

An example:

```
1024 constant pad-size
create pad pad-size allocate
```

The standard guarantees only 84 characters for `PAD` size, see the section [3.3.3.6 Other transient regions](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#subsubsection.3.3.3.6):

> The size of the scratch area whose address is returned by PAD shall be
>   at least 84 characters.

A good Forth-system should certainly provide the available size for `PAD` (see [environmental queries](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:env)) and a good program should either be limited by 84 chars or determines the available size. Using the buffers that indeterminate in length is a bad practice that can lead to the memory corruption bugs or even a vulnerability in general case.

The free space in the dictionary can be determined via [`UNUSED`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/UNUSED) word. But this space cannot be safely used without allocating — since many Forth implementations use this space by themselves. For example, all the buffers mentioned in the section [3.3.3.6](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#subsubsection.3.3.3.6) can be located in the dictionary free space region. But, by the standard, `PAD` buffer **must not overlap** with other buffers in memory. So it is need to know the particular Forth-system implementation details to determine the safe `offset` value and define `PAD` that will use the dictionary free space. The most reliable way to know these details — read the particular Forth-system source codes.

Even in that case it is also good to define something like:

```
: pad-size ( -- u ) unused offset - ; \ assuming that no other buffers after PAD
: pad-buf ( -- addr u ) pad pad-size ;
```

Comment: ruvim - thanks for taking the time to respond.  And I agree that it is indeed a safe location. But I'm reluctant to accept your answer as it is limited to PAD-SIZE in length.  The intention of the PAD word, I believe, is that it is indeterminate in length.  My PAD example definition is indeterminate in length; it's just the safe distance from HERE to PAD that I'm uncertain about.

Comment: I have updated the answer. It is need to read the particular Forth-system source codes to find a safe `offset` value for this system.